# How to create polynomial features from non-numeric variables?

Tags: r, feature-engineering

I want to create a polynomial feature (GarageGrade) that combines garage quality (GarageQual) with garage condition (GarageCond) via multiplication. The values for GarageQual and GarageCond are given as characters: Po (Poor), Fa (Fair), TA (Typical), Gd (Good), Ex (Excellent).

```
str(combi$GarageQual)
```

Return:  chr [1:2919] "TA" "TA" "TA" "TA" "TA" "TA" "TA" "TA" "Fa" "Gd" "TA" ...

```
str(combi$GarageCond)
```

Return:  chr [1:2919] "TA" "TA" "TA" "TA" "TA" "TA" "TA" "TA" "TA" "TA" "TA" ...

To start, I factored them:

```
combi$GarageQual <- factor(combi$GarageQual)
str(combi$GarageQual)
```

Return: Factor w/ 5 levels "Ex","Fa","Gd",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2 3 ..

```
combi$GarageCond <- factor(combi$GarageCond)
str(combi$GarageCond)
```

Return: > Factor w/ 5 levels "Ex","Fa","Gd",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...

Now I would like to replace the vector of factor level names

```
c("NA", "Po", "Fa", "TA", "Gd", "Ex")
```

with a numeric vector

```
c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

so these variables can be multiplied to create a combined feature, like this:

```
combi$GarageGrade <- combi$GarageQual * combi$GarageCond
```

What is the best way to accomplish my end goal of a comprehensive GarageGradevariable that combines GarageQual with GarageCond? Should I have even factored the levels to begin with or should I have replaced the characters directly with numerics? And if so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight forward way would be to create a vector of the five ratings in their correct order and then use `match` to convert the ratings to numeric.

```
set.seed(22)
grades <- c( "Po", "Fa", "TA", "Gd", "Ex")
GarageQual <- sample(grades, 20, replace = TRUE)
GarageCond <- sample(grades, 20, replace = TRUE)

match(GarageQual, grades) * match(GarageCond, grades)

[1]  4  6 15 12 20 20 12 20  6  4  5  8 15  5 15  1 15  1  4  6
```

An approach similar to what you've outlined above (convert to factor then to numeric) would work provided the factor levels were specified so that they're in the correct order.

```
as.numeric(factor(GarageQual, levels = grades)) * as.numeric(factor(GarageCond, levels = grades))

[1]  4  6 15 12 20 20 12 20  6  4  5  8 15  5 15  1 15  1  4  6
```

Comment: Awesome thank you @Jay, it works! Follow-up question: If I want to do this for multiple variables, is there a way to apply the grades all together? Here are the variables that get the grades vector: qual_cols <- c("ExterQual", "ExterCond", "BsmtQual", "BsmtCond", "HeatingQC", "KitchenQual", "FireplaceQu", "GarageQual", "GarageCond", "PoolQC")

Comment: Yes, take a look at `?lapply`.   Something like `sapply(combi[qual_cols], match, grades)` would probably be what you need.